# Start PHP-Session when MouseOver

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

```
$("#profile_bar").mouseover(function(){

    <?php $_SESSION['sessionasdf'] = 'asdf'; ?>

});
```

Hello! I have been busy with this for an hour, but I'm deadbrain now. Can someone help me out or give me a hint? Is the function I wrote above, even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Javasript is a client side, while PHP is a server side language.. You have to use a technique called AJAX if you want to do this

Comment: So I can't combine PHP and Javascript?

Comment: @Mossawi nope - you could use a cookie - set it with JavaScript/jQuery and then get the cookie using PHP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an Ajax Request to do this. You can't simply start a session in a script that's already been loaded.

```
$("#profile_bar").mouseover(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "sessionStartPage.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("session has begun. Refreshing page now");
            location.reload(); //reload the page to load session variables
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Omg you're genius! I forgot this one!

Comment: hehe thanks.as a new user you should be aware that if you find an answer helpful you should accept it by tick checking it on the left.

Comment: Thanks @ladiesMan217 - Just ticked!

Answer (score 0):

As I said you have to use a technique called AJAX..
So its time to start learning:)
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

PHP run on server, JQuery(the javascript) run on browser.That's different.
And you can start the session at every page on server, rather than by the event on browser.